# How to reduce remote SQL Server loads?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, networking, network-programming

I want to create an application in C# with client and server sides. It will work over local network. Client sides must check for updates on a remote SQL Server. Lets say we've set update time interval to 2 seconds. If i have 20 client side applications, then they'll send query to the remote SQL Server every 2 sec and it will load server quite a lot. Now I want to know is there any way to reduce server load or it's only way to check for updates?

Comment: What is the data do you need to check for so often?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my point of view, there is no need to allow clients to connect the DB serer directly.  There should be one more tier here which will only connect to the server and cache information about the updates.  Your clients should connect to this additional information and work with the cached info.

**UPDATE**
As far as I understand, the problem appears because all your clients ping your DB server every two seconds.  The solution to this problem is to create a special module which will only have access to the DB server and asks it for the update.  For example, every two seconds.  If the update is ready, it should be able to fetch it from the DB and store.  This is what I meant under the additional tier.

Now, let's return to your clients.  They should be able to communicate with this module and get information from it about a ready  update (this information is cached and thus it is really fast to obtain it.  Also you needn't ping the server at every client request). If update is ready, fetch it to the client side and work on client side.

As for the communication between this additional tier and clients.  Since you are working with .NET, I would suggest that you take a look at the WCF which, from my point of view, becomes a standard approach of implementing the between-process communication in .NET.  There are a lot of information in the network about it, I will post the links shortly.

Here is my favorite WCF book:

[Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997)

MSDN entry:

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @user841470: In other words call a middle tier layer. You could use something like a SqlCacheDependency that caches a query or table. This way the cache always has the latest data. This could be implemented as a Web Service or WCF Service which is doing the caching. The app calls the web/WCF service, to which the relevant data is returned.

Comment: but in this case i need to write bunch of client side ip adresses to server side pc, how can i automate this process?

Comment: @Tural T.  You needn't write a bunch of ip addresses using WCF. All you need to do is to publish an end-point on the server side which is known by the client.  The client will connect to the WCf service and obtain the required information.

Comment: Clients can communicate with mid-tier using Publish-Subscribe messaging, so clients just subscribing for a specific update type and thats it, pubsub model effectively reduce redundant periodic checks from client to mid-tier.

Comment: If I understand you properly, you suggest the server to notify clients that the update is ready and then clients to download them.  Right?